# Totally path disconnected spaces are $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

A [totally path disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_path_disconnected) space is a space $X$ whose path-connected components are all singletons.  In other words, all continuous functions $[0,1]\to X$ must be constant.

Every [totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) space is totally path disconnected (since path components are contained in connected components).  And totally disconnected spaces are $T_1$ (since connected components are always closed).

But the following more general result is also true:

> **Proposition:** Every totally path disconnected space is $T_1$.

This will allow to update a result in [pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000049).  Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: This has now been updated in pi-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is totally path disconnected, then obviously every subspace of $X$ is totally path disconnected. In particular, every two-element subspace is totally path disconnected, hence discrete. Thus, $X$ is T1.

Additional note as requested:  
if $X = \{0, 1\}$ is totally path disconnected, then it is discrete: 
Assume not, then w.l.o.g. $\{1\}$ is not open.
Hence
$f: [0,1] \rightarrow X, 
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < \frac{1}{2} \\ 1, & x \ge \frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$  
is continuous, but not constant.

Obviously, a space is T1, iff every two-element subspace is T1, iff every two-element subspace is discrete.

Comment: Would you mind expanding slightly on a two element subspace being totally path disconnected implies it's discrete? (mention cases of indiscrete topology and Sierpinski space).  That way we can refer to it in pi-base!  (and why that implies T1 maybe?)

Answer (score 1):

Let X be  a totaly path disconnected space and let $a,b \in X$ be distinct points.
Define $f:[0,1] \to X$ by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} b, & x \in [0,1) \\ a, & x=1 \end{cases}$$

Notice that this function can't be continous as otherwise $a$ and $b$ are in the same path component.
Thus there exist an open set $U$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open,now the preimages of $f$ are $\emptyset, [0,1), \{1\}, [0,1]$ and the only one that is not open is $\{1\}$ and thus $f^{-1}(U) = \{1\}$ so $U$ has to contain $a$ and not $b$.

And thus $X$ is $T_1$

Comment: Interesting approach.

Comment: In the list of preimages of subsets of $X$, the last one should be $[0, 1]$, not $X$.